# How to set cron job to run every minute between 11 PM to 12AM Midnight

Tags: cron

I am setting a `Cron Job` to run every minute between `10 PM to 11 PM` as below and its working fine.

```
*/1  22-23  *   *   *
```

But when I want to set up it between `11PM to 12AM (Midnight)`as below

```
*/1 23-00   *   *   *
```

Its showing error as low limit value no. (i.e 23) should be less than higher limit (i.e 00).
I have searched on google (or say `stackoverflow` :D)  but have not find any way to run a `cron job` between `11PM-12AM`.

Comment: do you want from 23.00 up to 00.00 or up to 23.59? If it is the latter, `*/1 23 * * *` would do; if it is the former, you need to add one specific for 00.00: `0 0 * * *`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After doing some research on google I find its answer and it is very easy.

Just include a particular hour or range (between 0,23) in hour column i.e 2nd columns

```
*  22-23,23,0-9   *   *   *
```

This will run a con  job for every minute starting from `10:00 PM` to `09:00 AM`

Comment: You don't need the `/1` for the minutes field and technically the `22-23` is redundant (so it could just be `* 22,23,0-9   * * *` say) but thanks for the useful Q&A

Comment: @PeterGibson why not * 22-23,0-9   * * *

Comment: @Andrew that should work fine too. The range is inclusive.